# UIView spring animation with scale and alpha

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have this code:

```
thermAssist.alpha = 0
thermAssist.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.thermalAssistant?.transform = .identity
        self?.thermalAssistant?.alpha = 1
    }, completion: nil)
```

It works, but I need spring effect only for transform change, not for the alpha. I need alpha to change from 0 to 1 and stay 1. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by separating the animation for scaling and opacity change and running these separate animations simultaneously, I have tried using `CABasicAnimation` and `CASpringAnimation` and finally put them in a `CATransaction` to run them simultaneously

```
        let springAnim = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        springAnim.fromValue = 0.1
        springAnim.toValue = 1
        springAnim.duration = 1.4
        springAnim.damping = 0.4
        springAnim.fillMode = .forwards
        springAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false


        let alphaAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        alphaAnim.fromValue = 0
        alphaAnim.toValue = 1
        alphaAnim.duration = 1.4
        alphaAnim.fillMode = .forwards
        alphaAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        CATransaction.begin()
        animationView.layer.add(springAnim, forKey: "test")
        animationView.layer.add(alphaAnim, forKey: "test2")
        CATransaction.commit()
```

**OP:**

[image]